# TFS2017 Release Management TFVC Artifacts Source - only a changeset

Tags: tfs, ms-release-management, tfvc

On the Artifacts tab of the release definition editor I can choose as artifacts source type the "Team Foundation Version Control" in the Link an artifact source pop-up.

According with the [documentation](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/concepts/definitions/release/artifacts#sources) it's possible to specify a certain changeset to be used as a source:

> When you link a TFVC branch, you can specify the changeset to be
>   deployed when creating a release.

But in the editor is possible to select only the root (e.g. $/FooBarProject).

How can I specify to download only a specific changeset? I don't need to download the entire repository when I need just one script.

TFS Version 15.112.26301.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you specify a changeset, you're specifying a specific changeset for the entire repository. There's no way to conditionally restrict it to just the contents of that changeset.

If you need a specific file or subset of files, you should publish it as a build artifact.

Comment: So there is now way to specify the changeset in the release/artifacts editor?

Comment: You can specify a changeset when you create a release.